# Eclipse MAT tool thread display

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, eclipse-mat

As a beginner of MAT tool, I am using it to analyze some issue. But I have no idea what it means for those threads under a class instance. Just as the picture shows (under the leak suspects tab).

[image]

Does it mean, those threads are waiting for the resource (the class instance)?

Comment: @greg You are right. I checked the stack, those threads are in runnable status. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No these threads are not waiting, they can run normally. This means that the object of given `***Service` class is stored in the local variable in some stack frame of given thread which was running when you created the memory dump. The purpose of this view is to show you not only the biggest objects, but the reasons why they cannot be garbage collected. Here the reason is that it's stored in local variable.